# How to allocate spring-context?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am absolutely confused with application context in spring. If i use spring (simple spring) create a beans.xml and then invoke Application context from (for example) main() method.

```
ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext
            ("C:/Users/ZARA/workspace/HelloSpring/src/Beans.xml");
```

all works well. But I don't understand if i move file on directory above or in another directory(for example) it will be ok?

in spring-mvc there is context for each DispatcherServlet which i create and where i specify some beans, there is common context for all servlets, how to specify this? in web.xml? 
in general, please explain me this moment (I read spring in action, i undesrstand almost all, but these tricky moment isn't shown there.

Comment: In MVC, there are two different context, Application context which is root application context (only one), WebApplicationContext which can be multiple based on how many dispatcher servlets you create. Spring will by default load file named “xxx-servlet.xml” from your webapps WEB-INF folder where xxx is the servlet name in web.xml.

Comment: For Application Context declaration: If you are not explicitly declaring the context configuration file name in web.xml using the contextConfigLocation param, Spring will search for the applicationContext.xml under WEB-INF folder and throw FileNotFoundException if it could not find this file.

Comment: Should I specify base application context for entire app in web.xml? And others for servlets in ****-servlet.xml? And i should write these config in web.xml(for spring-mvc)? 


Only for consolidation my knowleadge(:

Comment: Application Context will be specified in applicationContext.xml file under WEB-INF folder. See this link for detailed explanation : http://javabeat.net/spring-mvc-application-context/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [FileSystemXmlApplicationContext java doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.html):

> Standalone XML application context, taking the context definition files from the file system or from URLs, interpreting plain paths as relative file system locations (e.g. "mydir/myfile.txt"). Useful for test harnesses as well as for standalone environments.

The key words here are **context definition files**, so you can pass paths to as many xml-files, as you want. Besides that, you can create an application context and pass it to the new one as a parent:

```
FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(String[] configLocations, ApplicationContext parent)
```

Thus you can easily create the needed hierarchy of contexts.

```
       ApplicationContext parentContext = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext
            ("C:/some/path/ParentBeans.xml");

       ApplicationContext childContext = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext
            (new String[]{"C:/some/path/ChildBeans1.xml", "C:/some/path/ChildBeans2.xml"}, parentContext);
```

> if i move file on directory above all in another directory(for example) it will be ok?

As long as your path to file is correct and reachable - it's Ok.